# Simple way of reading a two dimensional array into Python

Tags: python

The output of one of my programs is a two-dimensional array, e.g.

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9]]
```

of indeterminate length. I write this output as a single line to a file geno_matrix, which I then need to read into another program for analysis and processing. I need to read this into the other program as another 2 dimensional array.

Obviously, splitting by `,` won't work because I'll wind up with a list of brackets and individual numbers. If I do

```
for line in geno_matrix:
    vec = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
```

this will separate all entries (and brackets). I've also tried to

```
vec = line.rstrip('\n').split(',[')
```

which returns a list

```
['[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9]]']
```

so that `vec[0]` is the string (not an array) `'[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9]]'`, which brings me back to the original split problem.  What's the simplest way to read the original 2-d list in as such with Python?

Comment: You could try using `json`

Comment: `json.loads('[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9]]')`

Comment: Thank you, that works. I wasn't aware of the json encoder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ast`'s `literal_eval` function:

```
from ast import literal_eval
literal_eval('[[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9]]')
```

will give you
`[[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9]]` as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this gives you a list of strings, each string representing a vector:

```
"[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9]]".lstrip('[[').rstrip(']]').split(r'],[')
```

as so:

```
['1,2,3', '4,5,6,7', '8,9']
```

You can then split individual strings to lists.

Comment: I had thought about that approach, but assumed that there was a more "elegant" way of splitting a list of lists.